# iphone memory leaks with CoreData

Tags: iphone, core-data, memory-leaks, instruments

I was checking my app for memory leaks using instruments and I got the following  NSConcreteMutableData GeneralBlock memory leaks.When I checked it was from the following code.

```
    NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load data : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

error = nil;
```

My fetchResultCntroller initialization looks exactly like apple examples.Is there something I'm missing. I'm debugging it on Simulator 3.0. I would appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for memory leaks on the device, rather than on the simulator.  The simulator has some funny memory leaks of its own.